# Is it possible to compute an ANOVA table for R regression objects that do not have an anova function (specifically heavy::heavyLm)?

Tags: r, anova

I am performing a robust regression with the [heavy package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heavy/heavy.pdf). I'd like to get an idea of the contributions of the terms to explaining the variance. In a simple regression with `lm()`, `anova()` (which calls `anova.lm()`) would be used for this. Unfortunately, `heavy::heavyLm` returns a `heavyLm` class object that does apparently not inherit from `lm`, hence `anova.lm()` is not called and `anova()` cannot be used:

```
rr <- heavy:heavyLm(<some_formula>, data=<some_data_frame>, family=Cauchy())
anova(rr)
# Error in UseMethod("anova") : 
#   no applicable method for 'anova' applied to an object of class "heavyLm"
```

**Ideas**

- Attempting to force calling `anova.lm()` somehow and tricking it into believing that `rr` is of type `heavyLm` will certainly not work. I notice that [`anova.lm()`](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/lm.R) does not simply compute

  ```
  sum((rr$model[,2]-rr$coefficients[[2]]*mean(rr$model[,2]))**2)
  ```

  i.e. (x - coefficient(x) * mean(x))**2, but it performs computations with `rr$effects` and `rr$qr`, which only exist if `rr` is of type `lm`, not of type `heavyLm`. I am not even sure how to do this by hand.
- Is there another way do compute an ANOVA table? I notice that there are other functions such as `aov()`. However, I am not sure if these would not simply redo the regression as normal OLS like in `lm()` (instead of sticking with the robust regression). Also:

  ```
  aov(rr)
  # Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object '' not found
  ```
- Is there an alternative to the ANOVA table that can be used for the same purpose and can be obtained more easily or from `heavyLm` objects directly? The elements of an `heavyLm` object appear to be

  ```
  names(rr)
  [1] "dims"          "family"        "settings"      "coefficients"  "sigma2"        "fitted.values" "residuals"     "weights"       "distances"     "acov"          "logLik"

  [12] "numIter"       "control"       "speed"         "converged"     "call"          "na.action"     "contrasts"     "xlevels"       "terms"         "model"
  ```

**Software** is R 3.6.3 with heavy 0.38.196 on Linux 5.5.9.

Comment: the QR part is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition , which is to get individual representation of each variable .. not very familiar with how heavy lm works, so I am not sure is qr can be applied just like that

Comment: a way to get around, is to fit a reduced model without the variable of interest and check the change in rss... note this only works if your variables are not collinear

Comment: @StupidWolf Thanks. I noticed that `rr$qr` is only used to provide the index of the effect in `rr$effects`, which are "are the uncorrelated single-degree-of-freedom values obtained by projecting the data onto the successive orthogonal subspaces generated by the QR decomposition" according to [the help](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/effects). `heavy` does not provide effects, but [does use QR decomposition](https://github.com/cran/heavy/blob/master/src/mlm_fit.c). But I do not think it is easy to get the effects out of there without rewriting the package.